Disabling a single DataGrid Cell in C# WPF
I need to disable buttons in DataGrid cells based o a boolean value. When i try the code below, the entire row gets disabled.
What i've tried
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>

Button in row
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Azione" Width="3*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="btnEffettuaOperazioni_Click">
                <TextBlock Text="Effettua operazioni"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>


Here is a working exemple. Take a look :
If the checkbox is checked, only the button is disabled
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<ScrollViewer>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Azione" Width="3*" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button Click="btnEffettuaOperazioni_Click"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                            <TextBlock Text="Effettua operazioni"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        private void Populate()
        {
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
            Items.Add(new Data() { IsChecked = true, Value = "Lorem Ipsum" });
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Populate();
        }

        private void btnEffettuaOperazioni_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}


@freedmaan Don't forget to make this response as accepted to make this question as resolved

Oh right, I think i've done it now
